# Recursive function in javascript - how gets resovled in scope chain

Tags: javascript, recursion

In JavaScript when a function calls itself, how does it get resolved in scope chain ?

```
function myFunc(){
    myFunc()
}
```

I know that it's bad code and will run forever.

Comment: It will cause infinite loop. Bad code.

Comment: Scope is determined by how a function is defined, not by how it is called, so "the same way as normal".

Comment: This is infinite loop. (No matter what kind of languages you use.) Please see recursion rules.

Comment: my question is that how it gets resolved ? and i know that its bad code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a function *declaration* (like yours above), within the function, the function's name is in scope. It's added to the *variable binding object* of the execution context where it was declared. This is covered in turgid prose in [Section 10.4.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3) and [Section 10.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5). of the specification.

So for instance, consider:

```
function foo() {

    function bar() {
    }
}
```

When you call `foo`, that creates an execution context for the call. That context has a variable binding object associated with it (I'm skipping some details), which you can loosely think of as the "scope" for that call. One of the things that happens before any step-by-step code within `foo` is executed is that all of the function declarations within it are evaluated and the names of those functions added to the variable binding object for the context of the call to `foo`. (This is also where `foo`'s argument names and local variables are stored.) Since `bar` *closes over* that context, it has access to the bindings, including the one giving it its name.

The same thing (effectively) happens when global code is entered initially, with the global context rather than a call to `foo`.

> my question is that how it gets resolved

You can think of JavaScript scopes as [Matryoshka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll): One inside another inside another. When the JavaScript engine encounters an identifier (like `bar` in my example above), it looks at the innermost "scope" (variable binding object) to see if it has an entry for that identifier. If it does, it uses it. If not, it looks at the containing scope to see if *it* has it, and so on, and so on, until we reach global scope. If the identifier isn't resolved at any point in this "scope chain", and if you're trying to read a value from it, that causes a `ReferenceError`. (If you're trying to *set* a value on it, it either creates an implicit global — see my article [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) — or causes a `ReferenceError` if you're in strict mode.)

This resolution is covered by [Section 10.3.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3.1), [10.2.2.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2.2.1), and others, but they're **really** hard going. :-)

Comment: can u explain it in easy way. my thinking is that when i call myFunc inside myFunc its resolved from its parent context am i right here?

Comment: what do u say about my above thoughts

Comment: i think i am also correct on my thoughts

Comment: *"inside myFunc its resolved from its parent context am i right here"* For a function *declaration*, like yours above, yes.

Comment: you mean if i declare function inside function or when i call the same function from inside the function ?

Comment: @abdulraziq: I mean when you declare a function at all: Its name is added to the scope in which you declare it. If the function refers to itself using its name, then that symbol is resolved by the containing scope (where it's declared). The reason I keep making a point of the word "declaration" is that JavaScript also has function *expressions*, which work differently.